# How to generate cross product of sets in specific order

Tags: algorithm, perl, set, combinatorics

Given some sets (or lists) of numbers, I would like to iterate through the cross product of these sets in the order determined by the sum of the returned numbers. For example, if the given sets are { 1,2,3 }, { 2,4 }, { 5 }, then I would like to retrieve the cross-products in the order

<3,4,5>,
<2,4,5>,
<3,2,5> or <1,4,5>,
<2,2,5>,
<1,2,5>

I can't compute all the cross-products first and then sort them, because there are way too many. Is there any clever way to achieve this with an iterator?

(I'm using Perl for this, in case there are modules that would help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two sets A and B, we can use a min heap as follows.

1. Sort A.
2. Sort B.
3. Push (0, 0) into a min heap H with priority function (i, j) |-> A[i] + B[j]. Break ties preferring small i and j.
4. While H is not empty, pop (i, j), output (A[i], B[j]), insert (i + 1, j) and (i, j + 1) if they exist and don't already belong to H.

For more than two sets, use the naive algorithm and sort to get down to two sets. In the best case (which happens when each set is relatively small), this requires storage for O(√#tuples) tuples instead of Ω(#tuples).

---

Here's some Python to do this. It should transliterate reasonably straightforwardly to Perl. You'll need a heap library from CPAN and to convert my tuples to strings so that they can be keys in a Perl hash. The set can be stored as a hash as well.

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def largest_to_smallest(lists):
  """
  >>> print list(largest_to_smallest([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4], [5]]))
  [(3, 4, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 2, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 2, 5), (1, 2, 5)]
  """
  for lst in lists:
    lst.sort(reverse=True)
  num_lists = len(lists)
  index_tuples_in_heap = set()
  min_heap = []
  def insert(index_tuple):
    if index_tuple in index_tuples_in_heap:
      return
    index_tuples_in_heap.add(index_tuple)
    minus_sum = 0  # compute -sum because it's a min heap, not a max heap
    for i in xrange(num_lists):  # 0, ..., num_lists - 1
      if index_tuple[i] >= len(lists[i]):
        return
      minus_sum -= lists[i][index_tuple[i]]
    heappush(min_heap, (minus_sum, index_tuple))
  insert((0,) * num_lists)
  while min_heap:
    minus_sum, index_tuple = heappop(min_heap)
    elements = []
    for i in xrange(num_lists):
      elements.append(lists[i][index_tuple[i]])
    yield tuple(elements)  # this is where the tuple is returned
    for i in xrange(num_lists):
      neighbor = []
      for j in xrange(num_lists):
        if i == j:
          neighbor.append(index_tuple[j] + 1)
        else:
          neighbor.append(index_tuple[j])
      insert(tuple(neighbor))
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! Could you give me a pointer for "the naive algorithm and sort to get down to two sets"?

Comment: If you want A x B x C x D, then compute A x B, sort it, compute C x D, sort it, and then compute (A x B) x (C x D).

Comment: To minimize space usage, you should group the sets so that the naively computed Cartesian products are about the same size.

Comment: @user635541, I typically have about 20 sets with 1-5 members each, so even computing the cross product of half of them is infeasible. But I guess I could use your min heap idea all the way down: to get A x B x C x D, use a min heap iterator for A x B and another one for C x B; for the main iterator, the two lists A and B would be replaced by two functions that call the relevant sub-iterator or retrieve the desired value from a cache. At the end of the process, the caches would contain the whole cross-products, but I usually only need the first few thousand iterations. Does that sound right?

Comment: If you only need the first few thousand, that changes everything. It's easy enough to adapt the approach above to k dimensions; the only reason I didn't before is that if you pull the whole list, then there's no space savings. I'll post some code in a bit.