# All possible lists of pairs from two lists

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations

Suppose I have two lists of items. The two lists may or may not be the same length.

How can I generate all the lists of all possible pairs of items, where a pair consists of an item from each list? Each item can only be in a single pair.

So, if one list is:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

And the other list is:

```
(a, b)
```

Then the lists of all possible pairs would be:

```
(1a, 2b)
(1a, 3b)
(1b, 2a)
(1b, 3a)
(2a, 3b)
(2b, 3a)
```

(I'm implementing this in Perl, but obviously the algorithm is the important bit.)

Thanks in advance. My recursion foo isn't working!

Comment: Nearly an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149939/how-to-generate-cross-product-of-sets-in-specific-order

Comment: Those aren't pairs, they're pairs of pairs. Your problem description doesn't match your expected output!

Comment: @Robin Green: Actually, it appears to be the list of all possible pairings. Put another way, it's listing all possible one to one functions.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misunderstood. It makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks. You're right - the title was rubbish and so was some of the description. I've tried to make it a little clearer now. Of course, they're actually lists of pairs, rather than pairs of pairs. They're only pairs of pairs above because the second list just has two items in this simple example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub unordered_pairs {
    return if @_ < 2;
    my $first = shift;
    return (map [$first, $_], @_), unordered_pairs(@_);
}

sub cartesian_product {
    my @answers = [];
    for my $list (@_) {
        @answers = map {
            my $value = $_;
            map [@$_, $value], @answers
        } @$list;
    }
    return @answers;
}

sub possible_pairs_of_pairs {
    my ($list1, $list2) = @_;

    my @pairs1 = unordered_pairs(@$list1);
    my @pairs2 = unordered_pairs(@$list2);

    return map {
        [[$_->[0][0], $_->[1][0]], [$_->[0][1], $_->[1][1]]],
        [[$_->[0][0], $_->[1][1]], [$_->[0][1], $_->[1][0]]],
    } cartesian_product(\@pairs1, \@pairs2);
}
```

And sample usage:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @stuff = possible_pairs_of_pairs([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']);
print Dumper(\@stuff);
```

Be warned that if your lists have `$n` and `$m` elements, the final output will have `$n * ($n-1) * $m * ($m-1) / 2` elements.  This will blow up very quickly with larger lists.  Read http://perl.plover.com/Stream/stream.html for inspiration on how to not run out of memory with that kind of data structure.  (Or read *Higher Order Perl*, the book that eventually came out of that article.)